# Is mac sierra protecting me from erasing my hard drive and my sd card

Tags: macos

when I was trying to erase my sd card in fat16 format i entered the wrong device tree .(e.g. instead of writing disk3s2 i wrote disk2 when i executed the command it said permission denied(which was supposed to erase my whole drive).then when i again tried to format it the right way it again said permission denied.

```
newfs_msdos -F 16 /Volumes/KIRAN\ USB/dev/disk2s1
```

So here's my question why am I not able to format my drive and sd card via terminal

Comment: Your command should be `sudo newfs_msdos -F 16 /dev/disk2s1`  I don't know why you are including the mount point as well.

Comment: thanks for editing my question how do you add the terminal command in a grey rectangle?

Comment: @Doof There are two ways. You can either surround the command with the "backtick" character (`, typically found to the left of the "1" key), or you can prefix each command with four spaces, assuming the command will be on its own line.

Comment: Just a note - backtick is one of those that moves around depending on keyboard language. UK Eng it's left of z.

Comment: I saw the command line from another website

Answer (score 3):

Only the super user can normally perform this action, except when using the `diskutil` command, which incorrectly allows it. The full command you should use would be `sudo newfs_msdos -F 16 /dev/disk2s1`. You will have to enter your password to continue. Although, I would suggest using FAT32, because FAT16 is likely inappropriate for your SD card assuming you bought it sometime in the past decade. An even better option would be exFAT, assuming all the devices you'll be using this SD card in support it.

Comment: (At first i tried #sudo)oh ok actually i bought a new sd card and put it in my phone(android) it worked fine until i encrypted it and decrypted it in a different phone then i put another sd card which was fat16 format it worked fine so i thought i could format the new sd card in fat16 but i solved it by formatting it in a different phone again and decrypted it.i was just scared i erased a sector of my hard drive and is it actually a big difference if i type disk2 instead of disk2s2 in the terminal command

Comment: `disk2` would refer to the entire disk, while `disk2s2` would refer to a single partition within the disk. You cannot format an entire disk as FAT, only a single partition, so disk2s2 would be what you'd use in this case.

Comment: i tried the command by using disk2 instead of disk2s2 but it shows "no such file or directory"

Comment: +1 for avoiding FAT16 [well... amongst other things. I realised the comment made me sound like that was the only reason I'd upvoted your answer ;)

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard "...which incorrectly allows it.": What do you mean with that?

Comment: @MaxRied disk formatting and partitioning are sensitive things and should require root access. Every other command does. You can't do much with 'gpt' or 'fdisk' without root access, for example. It has always seemed dangerous to me that 'diskutil' doesn't require root.